Upgrading TcpStream to TLS on mail server
I'm building my own mail server from scratch using rust. I've setup simple TCP server using tokio::new::TcpListener and use tokio::spawn to handle each connection. I wrapped the stream with BufReader. Then I send 220 response to the client. So now after client sending EHLO and then STARTTLS I want to upgrade the stream to use TLS. I know I could implement my own TLS, but that isn't the best idea. So my question is: How can I upgrade to TLS after the command.
Here is my code for generating certificates:
rm *.pem

openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -days 3650 -keyout ca-key.pem -out ca-cert.pem -subj "..."

echo "CA's self-signed certificate"
openssl x509 -in ca-cert.pem -noout -text

openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout server-key.pem -out server-req.pem -subj "..."
openssl x509 -in ca-cert.pem -noout -text

openssl x509 -req -in server-req.pem -days 3650 -CA ca-cert.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -CAcreateserial -out server-cert.pem -extfile server-ext.cnf

echo "Servers's self-signed certificate"
openssl x509 -in server-cert.pem -noout -text

openssl pkcs12 -export -out cert.pfx -inkey server-key.pem -in server-cert.pem -certfile ca-cert.pem

This is my basic implementation of native_tls, but the accept function doesn't work ofc.
// server.rs
loop {
    match server.accept().await {
        Ok((stream, address)) => {
            tokio::spawn(async {
                Connection::handle(stream).await;
            });
        }
        Err(e) => {
            error!("{e}");
        }
    }
}

// connection.rs fn handle
let mut buffer = String::new();

self.write("220 swiftmail.app ESMTP SwiftMail\r\n").await;

loop {
    match self.stream.read_line(&mut buffer).await {
        Ok(0) => break,
        Ok(_bytes) => {
            let parts = buffer.split_ascii_whitespace().collect::<Vec<&str>>();
            let command = buffer.clone();
            // STARTTLS / EHLO
            let command_name = parts.get(0).unwrap();

            match command_name {
                "EHLO" => self.ehlo(command).await,
                "STARTTLS" => self.starttls(command).await,
                _ => {}
            };
        },
        _ => {}
    }

    buffer.clear();
}

// starttls.rs
conn.write("220 GO HEAD\r\n").await;

let stream = conn.stream.get_mut(); // &mut TcpStream

let mut file = File::open("C:/Dev/mail-server/src/cert/cert.pfx").unwrap();
let mut identity = vec![];
file.read_to_end(&mut identity).unwrap();

let identity = Identity::from_pkcs12(&identity, "password").unwrap();

let acceptor = TlsAcceptor::new(identity).unwrap();
let acceptor = tokio_native_tls::TlsAcceptor::from(acceptor);


To upgrade a TCP connection to TLS in Rust after receiving a STARTTLS command, you can use the tokio_native_tls crate, which provides asynchronous TLS/SSL streams for use with Tokio. You've already got the basics in your question, but let's refine it and fit it into the context of your application.
Use tokio-native-tls and native-tls added to your Cargo.toml.
You should refactor your starttls function to upgrade the stream:
use tokio::net::TcpStream;
use tokio_native_tls::TlsAcceptor;
use native_tls::Identity;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Read;
use tokio::io::{AsyncReadExt, AsyncWriteExt};

async fn upgrade_to_tls(tcp_stream: TcpStream) -> tokio::io::Result<()> {
    let mut file = File::open("path_to_cert/cert.pfx").unwrap();
    let mut identity_data = vec![];
    file.read_to_end(&mut identity_data).unwrap();

    let identity = Identity::from_pkcs12(&identity_data, "password").unwrap();
    let tls_acceptor = native_tls::TlsAcceptor::new(identity).unwrap();
    let acceptor = TlsAcceptor::from(tls_acceptor);

    let mut tls_stream = acceptor.accept(tcp_stream).await.unwrap();

    // You can now read and write to `tls_stream` as your TLS-secured connection
    tls_stream.write_all("220 Ready for secure communication\r\n".as_bytes()).await?;

    // Example of reading from the stream
    let mut buffer = vec![0; 1024];
    let n = tls_stream.read(&mut buffer).await?;
    println!("Received: {}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&buffer[..n]));

    Ok(())
}

It means that you have to prepare TLS Identity first, e.g. from your PKCS12 (.pfx) file, which contains both the certificate and private key, create a native_tls::Identity instance. This identity is used by the TLS acceptor to perform the TLS handshake.
In your main connection handling loop, after receiving the STARTTLS command, you'll call this upgrade_to_tls function, passing the TCP stream (TcpStream) as an argument.
